# Can I pass Breeze JSON to search for entities using adapter

Tags: javascript, breeze

I have a scenario where I want to pass some JSON to Breeze and use my JsonResultsAdapter to search for entities at the top level nodes.  I think this would be really beneficial for returning updated entities in things like results from a POST operation.  (ie. Business Logic on the back-end receives an updated entity that associates new entities to the parent entity, then returns them in the success)

I know I could copy / paste my JsonResultsAdapter code into a new module to search for the entities and then materialize them with a createEntity and then override the entityState, but I wanted to check first whether this was possible natively.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want.  Are you trying to query or save? If querying you can add parameters, (which can be javascript structures) to your query that will in turn get serialized as json and available at the server endpoint.  Or am I missing something in your request.

Comment: Imagine I do a save as a POST and that save returns some updated entities that have been added on the server.  Is there anyway to tell Breeze 'Check these results for entities' similar to the way Breeze intercepts the query results?

Comment: The save results DO pass thru the DataService's JsonResultAdapter, so you could replace this JsonResultsAdapter for the duration of the save. However, you can't currently specify a JsonResultsAdapter just for the save.  This would be a reasonable change request.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Potentially, let me ponder on it for a bit and I can create a user voice to see if anyone else thinks it is a worthwhile request.

Comment: @JayTraband Pretty interesting find here - so I found out about the breeze.ajaxpost.js and implemented it to do what I mentioned above.  Instead of being forced to route my saveChanges through Breeze, which serializes the entities into it's own style of payload, I can serialize an object and use AjaxPost to send the data across the wire and then Breeze intercepts the results and processes them.  The only manual operation at that point is calling entity.entityAspect.acceptChanges() on each of the entities in the payload.  Seems like a very powerful way to handle this.

Comment: Are you actually changing the serialization format from the client, or just sending the same saveBundle via AjaxPost?

Comment: @JayTraband Related to my other question, I wrote a custom serializer that is ignoring the entityAspect, entityType, and parent navigation property to prevent implied recursivity when serializing to do a true 'custom save' method.